# Select items in user generated multidimensional array, whole column gets selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im building an app in which the user can input the height and width and generate a grid with those dimensions. Then when clicking in individual cells they can toggle them on or off. Im using a multidimensional array to display the individual state of each cell.

When clicking each cell, the coordinates get passed to an updater method that updates the multidimensional array state. The problem I'm encountering is that when clicking one item, the whole column gets toggled.

**When clicking coordinates column 0 and row 0 in a 3x3 multidimensional array**

**Expected new updated array**

```
[
[true, false, false],
[false, false, false],
[false, false, false]
]
```

**Current Output:**

```
[
[true, false, false],
[true, false, false],
[true, false, false]
]
```

I've checked if the correct coordinates are passed and they are correct. What seems to do the trick is only if I hard code a multidimensional array. I believe the issue happens when I generate a grid with the input coordinates.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

import Grid from '../Grid';
import InputView from '../InputView';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';

const App = () => {
  const [inputView, setInputView] = useState({ visible: true, rebuildingGrid: false });
  const [gridSize, setGridSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const [prevGridSize, setPrevGridSize] = useState(undefined);
  const [gridMatrix, setGridMatrix] = useState(undefined);

  const generateGrid = (size) => {
    var grid = [];
    var row = [];
    for(let i=0; i<size.width; i++) row.push(false);
    for(let j=0; j<size.height; j++) grid.push(row); 
    setGridMatrix(grid);

    // works hard coded
    // var test = [
    //   [false, false, false],
    //   [false, false, false],
    //   [false, false, false],
    // ];
    //  setGridMatrix(test);
  };

  const inputNewGrid = () => {
    setInputView({ visible: true, rebuildingGrid: true });
    setPrevGridSize(gridSize);
  };

  const toggleCell = (coords) => {
    var { row, col } = coords;
    var newGridMatrix = [...gridMatrix];
    newGridMatrix[row][col] = newGridMatrix[row][col] === false ? true : false;
    setGridMatrix(newGridMatrix);
    console.log(newGridMatrix);
  } 

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => console.log(gridMatrix)}>
        <h1>
          LOG MATRIX
        </h1>
      </div>
      { inputView.visible ? 
        <InputView 
          gridSize={gridSize}
          prevGridSize={prevGridSize}
          setGridSize={setGridSize}
          setInputView={setInputView} 
          generateGrid={() => generateGrid(gridSize)}
          rebuildingGrid={inputView.rebuildingGrid} 
        />
      : 
      (
        <>
          <Navigation inputNewGrid={inputNewGrid} />
          <Grid gridSize={gridSize} gridMatrix={gridMatrix} toggleCell={toggleCell} />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879038/creating-2d-array-from-section-of-other-2d-array-javascript/65879422#65879422) shows a simple method for selecting elements out of a multidimensional array given a staring column (x), row (x), a width (w) and height (h). I'm certain you can adapt it to your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are pushin the array `row` into the grid. Therefore every row inside the grid is "linked to" / referencing the same array => if you change one row, every row will change. To fix this, you would have to redeclare / reassign the `row` variable for everytime you want to push it into the grid.

The solution would be generating your grid somewhat like this:

```js
// if you want it to be one line
var grid = Array.from(Array(size.height)).map(() => Array(size.width).fill(false));

// other option
var grid = [];

for (let j = 0; j < size.height; j++) {
  var row = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size.width; i++) row.push(false);
  // another option would be:
  // var row = new Array(size.width).fill(false); < the "new" isn't necessary, but I think it looks better that way
  grid.push(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `generateGrid` logic is incorrect. Try printing the `grid` to console and you'll see. You can generate the array like this:

```
const generateGrid = (size) => {
    const grid = Array.from(Array(size.height)).map(row => Array(size.width).fill(false));
    setGridMatrix(grid);
  };
```

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) creates another array from the passed array-like or iterable object. In this case, an empty array with the length of either the height or width.